# Geo Location not works in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, cordova, geolocation

I have developed an application using phonegap to retrieve Geo Location.

```
function getLoc() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
function onSuccess(position) {
    var locInfo = new Object();

    locInfo.Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    locInfo.Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    locInfo.Altitude = position.coords.altitude;
    locInfo.Accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
    locInfo.AltitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
    locInfo.Heading = position.coords.heading;
    locInfo.Speed = position.coords.speed;

    alert(locInfo.Latitude + "   " + locInfo.Longitude);
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

above code is working fine in Android, iPhone and BlackBerry Simulator, but not in BlackBerry device. I'm using BlackBerry Torch for testing.

what could be the issue. pls reply.

Thanks :)

Comment: are you able to find a solution? i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set timeout for `getCurrentPosition`.

Comment: i tried that, but then it always getting timed out. is there any other ways to check that geo location works on the BlackBerry phone?